# How to increase the size of the pivot arrows and make them fixed in UWP?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

I have a pivot most used in the desktop and I want the arrows in the pivots to be fixed and not just to appear on hover and also to make the arrows larger(double) as they can be easily clicked.

I tried to find the parameter in the style component but unfortunately didn't have much luck there.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default style for the Pivot element. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx . Please update your required attribute to achieve the same. I updated height of the left and right navigation buttons(PreviousButton & NextButton) and thus it is reflecting in the UI
[image]

Here is the specific portion changes did in the default template:

```
<Button
    x:Name="PreviousButton"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}"
    Width="20"
    Height="72"
    UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"
    Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}"
    IsTabStop="False"
    IsEnabled="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Opacity="1"
    Background="Transparent" />
<Button
    x:Name="NextButton"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Template="{StaticResource NextTemplate}"
    Width="20"
    Height="72"
    UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"
    Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}"
    IsTabStop="False"
    IsEnabled="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Opacity="1"
    Background="Transparent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!